# How do I transfer a file to my server using PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, putty, scp

when calling SCP in PuTTY on my Win7 box, it doesn't let me use C:/, but I also have no idea *where* on my local machine it will look for files by default. None of program directory or user directory worked. For example, I saved file.txt next to PuTTY.exe, and also in C:\Users\Me but calling SCP file.txt file.txt in PuTTY failed both times with

> cp: cannot stat 'file.txt'

So, how do I transfer a file to my server using PuTTY?

EDIT: Also, calling `SCP file.txt myserver:file.txt` gives a similar error: `file.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: I dont think putty alone can do the job. WinSCP is a nice GUI tool for secure copy of files, Putty works very well for the job also using the command line tool called pscp.

Comment: I had the issue of using pscp to copy a file through an intermediate server.  This question was the base of me figuring out.  The full instructions on taking this question to the next step are here http://superuser.com/q/577663/57649

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution that doesn't use PuTTY: Connect to server with FileZilla using SFTP to transfer files.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried something like

```
pscp -l user1 c:\ftp\picture.jpg slacker1:/home/user1/pics
```

The [manual for Putty](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) suggests

> To send (a) file(s) to a remote server:
>
> `pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target`
>
> So to copy the
>   local file `c:\documents\foo.txt` to the server `example.com` as user `fred`
>   to the file `/tmp/foo` you would type:
>
> `pscp c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo`

---

Postscript

The [Putty download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) lets you download **`putty.zip`** - a complete set of Putty tools or you can just download the tools you need (in which case you might have downloaded putty.exe but not yet have downloaded pscp.exe)

Comment: I have putty installed.  I dont seem to have pscp available either within the putty shell or within my local shell.  Could you shed a bit more light?  Where do you run pscp from?  Cheers

Comment: @JonnyLeeds: I run it in a Windows command prompt (cmd) from the Putty installation directory e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe` in my case. You can either put the full path in double quotes (because of the spaces in it) or add the directory to your %PATH% (see other answers here for how to do that).

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but all I have in my putty folder is putty.exe, puttygen.exe and a ppk file

Comment: @JonnyLeeds: You can either download just pscp.exe from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html or download a putty.zip containing a complete, consistent set of the latest version of Putty tools and replace the sparse set you have.

Comment: Great answer.  One more tidbit: you can often use a period after the remote location's colon if you don't know where you want the file to go.  For instance: pscp -l username C:\dir\file.txt server:.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to initiate a file transfer back to/from local Windows from a SSH session opened in PuTTY window.

Though the recent versions of PuTTY support connection-sharing.

While you still need to run a compatible file transfer client (the `pscp` or the `psftp`), no new login is required, it automatically (if enabled) makes use of an existing PuTTY session.

To enable the sharing see:
[Sharing an SSH connection between PuTTY tools](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-sharing).

---

Alternative way, is to use [WinSCP, a GUI SFTP/SCP client](https://winscp.net/). While you browse the remote site, you can anytime open an SSH terminal to the same site using the *Open in PuTTY* command.

See [Opening Session in PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#open_putty_current).

With an additional setup, you can even make PuTTY automatically navigate to the same directory you are browsing with WinSCP.

See [Opening PuTTY in the Same Directory](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#putty_startup_directory).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find pscp as suggested above and ended up using WinScp.

It's a client side program with a GUI which picks up your putty configs.

Comment: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html offers pscp.exe and the similar psftp.exe file.  The http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty-0.63-installer.exe (for version 0.63, which is the latest version at the time of this writing) may be simplest for people who prefer being walked through an easy installation process using a GUI, while the putty.zip file also contains putty.exe and pscp.exe and psftp.exe

Answer (score 0):

1. In PSFTP open the folder you want to put the file in.
     Ex. cd filename
2. In the command line type: lcd pathtofolder
     Ex. lcd C:\Users\Lyn\Pictures
3. Click enter and type: put filename
     Ex. put lynhw1.pdf
4. Click enter and the file should be transferred

Hope it works for you as it does for me.
Note: I did this in PSFTP using Putty.

"PSFTP, the PuTTY SFTP client, is a tool for transferring files securely between computers using an SSH connection" - http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html

Download PSFTP on the http://www.putty.org/ webpage. Under download putty here.

Comment: Nope, please don't do that.  Encouraging people to use putty.org should not be done, and likewise I recommend people don't follow such advice. The [Latest Official PuTTY documentation's section about putty.org](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org) (e.g. [Version 0.77 of that documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/AppendixA.html#faq-putty-org)) is not referring to that domain positively.  More commended: Download PuTTY-related software from [the proper website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to automate this kind of file transfer via `.bat`:

```
@echo off

set pw=foobemcfoobar

set inp=input.lst

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%inp%) do (

echo %%i

echo y | C:\tmp\pscp.exe -C -agent -pw "%pw%" C:\tmp\files\foo.txt root@%%i:/tmp/

echo "=== Accepting SSH, copying ...==="

 )
```

(where `input.lst` is a text file with targets listed)

Comment: While perhaps relevant to the *topic*, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Also do not suggest people to blindly accept a host key using `echo y`. You lose security by doing so.

Comment: mhh agreed, the "echo y" is a security issue.
as for relevancy, I just took that file copy thought a step further because I was once in that very situation