# How to copy a file using pscp through an intermediary gateway server hop

Tags: ssh, putty, pscp

I have a linux jump box between me and a remote server.  I have seen a few posts on how to do this with scp (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host)), but I am on a Windows box, so the situation is slightly different.  I want to copy a file from my local windows machine, through a server setup as a gateway between the two.  I should be able to do a multi-hop through the intermediate server.  So something like this:

A -> B -> C

I don't want to copy the file to B, then log into B and copy the file again.  I'd like to be able to run pscp on a number of files to copy them over.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the best way to do this is to first establish a tunnel to the intermediate server (server B in the illustration).  Then pscp over this link.  I'll step through exactly what I did.

1) Create an SSH connection to serverB in PuTTY

[image]

2) For this connection create a tunnel that goes from port 2222 (you can pick another if you want) to serverC at port 22

[image]

3) Open a command window in Windows.  Navigate to where PuTTY/pscp is installed on your machine (if not on the Path already)

4) Enter the following command (substituting your own values for those in {}):

> c:\putty> pscp -P 2222 -pw {myPasswordOnRemoteMachine} c:\dev\fileIWantToCopy.txt {myusername}@127.0.0.1:/tmp

5) On the remote machineC, the file should be in the /tmp directory

Comment: An easier alternative on Windows is to just use WinSCP and use the tunnel feature built into that app.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I found to this problem, was to not use pscp at all.  Just use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) to copy the file over.

1. Enter your final server address (i.e. server 'C' in the question) in the session page and select SCP.
   [image]
2. Click on 'Advanced...'.  Go to Connection>Tunnel.  Enter your jump server info here (i.e. Server 'B').
   [image]
3. Now just login with either your keyfile or password and you'll be tunneled in.

Answer (score 0):

My even more complicated situation:
    A -> B -> C -> D ->E

```
I used PuTTY and FileZilla

A my Windows machine, 
B and C are gateways (very limited functionality)
D is the first Linux Machine and 
E is the target Linux Machine

I use PuTTY to: 
    ssh into B (w/username password) (IP of B is predefined in PuTTY) then
    ssh into C (w/username password) then manually
    ssh into D (w/username password) then manually
    ssh into E (at least this uses pubic key login so no uid/password!)

Once this is setup I then add tunnel to the IP of the final machine E in PuTTY thus:
    L7777 172.123.124.125:22



OK now fire up FileZilla:

File > SiteManager:
Setup new connection to:
Host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 7777
Protocol SFTP
Ask for password...

Connect!
```